# Multithreading weird behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been going through some basic multithreading examples, and tried implementing some code to see how
thread priorities work:

```
class PriorityThreading extends Thread {

private static boolean stop = false;
private int count = 0;

public PriorityThreading(String name) { 
    super(name);
}

public void run() {
    do {
        count++;
    }while(stop==false && count<10000000 );
    stop = true;
}

public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
    PriorityThreading thread = new PriorityThreading("thread 1");
    PriorityThreading thread2 = new PriorityThreading("thread 2");
    PriorityThreading thread3 = new PriorityThreading("thread 3");
    
    
    thread.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
    thread2.setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread3.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
    
    thread.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
    
    thread.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    
    
    System.out.println(thread.getName() + " " + thread.count);
    System.out.println(thread2.getName() + " " + thread2.count);
    System.out.println(thread3.getName() + " " + thread3.count);
    
}
}
```

And I constantly get this output:
thread 1 10000000
thread 2 10000000
thread 3 10000000

This output is very confusing to me as:

1. I expected only 1 thread to have reached this total, due to the while loop having to be stopped after the first thread had finished and stop=true
2. Secondly, I expected only thread1 with the highest priority to have reached the max total.

I would really appreciate any explanation of why this is occurring,

Thanks.

Comment: `stop==false` -> `!stop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have thread priorities and all down perfectly.  The only issue here is that `stop` doesn't necessarily have the same value on all threads.  Each thread caches its own value for `stop` in thread-local memory.  When one thread sets its value of `stop` to `true`, the other threads don't necessarily "see" that change.  The fix is simple; just declare `stop` as `volatile` like so:

```
private static volatile boolean stop = false;
```

This keeps the variable in main memory, therefore forcing the threads to communicate with one another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the "volatile" and it did initially seem to work, but when I ran the code again, I was still getting instances where I would have 2 threads with the same "count", is this normal??

Comment: Yes, that is normal.  That just happens when 2 threads reach 10000000 at the same time, and so when they started the loop iteration, `stop` was false for both threads, they each incremented `count`, and then they both set `stop` to true so no more iterations occurred.  You can prevent this using a synchronized block, but that would defeat the purpose of thread priorities, since all the threads would be waiting on the monitor lock anyway.  Not to mention nothing would be happening in parallel, so it would kinda defeat the purpose of multi-threading as a whole, too.

Comment: Okay, I think I am understanding this a little more now, so basically the priorities just increase the likely hood of a threads execution being carried out before other threads of lower priorities?

Comment: Yup!  You hit the nail on the head, that's exactly what they do.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: The definition of priority in Java threads is rather vague. The [API] (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) says _ Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority_ and that is all. [This article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/thread-priorities.html) even says: _A JVM is free to implement priorities in any way it chooses, including ignoring the value._